# Getting attributes for list of coordinates using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I am a beginner with GIS, looking to achieve a relatively simple goal. I have two things:

1) A map with a layer on it as in the following picture:

[image]

2) A list of coordinates.

For each pair of coordinates, I wish to get the variable STAT11 for the polygon in which the coordinate pair is located.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: You want a table with coordinates and STAT11 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start by [adding the coordinate pairs as a point layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_7757B49A5A83421296C96DE62E2A70EA) to the map
2. Join polygon data to the coordinate points using [Spatial Join tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) with Point layer as Target Features and polygon layer as Join Features. This will create a new Point feature class with both Point and polygon attributes.
3. If you want the XY coordinates visible in the attribute table use tool [Add XY Coordinates](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm)
4. [Export as table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/exporting-tables.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I did the first step but have a problem in step 2. Regardless of whether I try points to polygons or polygons to points, the OK button remains gray and unclickable. Why is that?
What I did is to add the coordinates by using "Add XY coordinates" and editing the coordinates to adhere to the WGS1984 Geograpic Coordinate System. Once it's added, right click the table I added from .csv, and click join, select "Join data from another layer based on spatial location". I want to click ok, but it is not clickable.

Comment: Are you using spatial join tool? Does not sound like it if you are right-clicking a csv table

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. I thought that what I did is what you meant. How can I access the Spatial Join Tool? I followed the link you provided but could not understand if this is a package I need to add or what..

Comment: Geoprocessing menu - Search for tools - type in Spatial Join - ENTER - Click the tool

Comment: Found it thanks. Now the problem is that in the joined tabled, the for the variable I am interested in, STAT11, all entries are `<null>`. Why is this?

Comment: Either you are doing something wrong or no polygons overlap with your coordinate points. Can you verify that they overlap in the map?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

1. Create point feature class using your coordinates.
2. Add it to your project.
3. Use `Select by location` tool to select all polygons (use `Intersect` parameter).
4. Open polygons attribute table.
5. Push `Show only selected` button.
6. Copy all rows from attribute table.